# AttributeError: 'EnvelopesApi' object has no attribute 'select_header_accept'

Tags: docusignapi

i am trying to search and get envelopes from docusign using this code

```
def get_envelopes_by_email(email_address):
    from docusign_esign import EnvelopesApi
    from core.services.docusign import envelopes_api
    from django.conf import settings

    api_client = envelopes_api.get_envelopes_api_client()

    envelopes_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)

    from docusign_esign import ApiException

    try:
        # Use the EnvelopesApi to search for envelopes based on the email address
        search_options = {
            #'from_date': '1900-01-01',  # Adjust as needed
            #'to_date': '2099-12-31',  # Adjust as needed
            "email": email_address
        }

        results = envelopes_api.list_status_changes(settings.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID, **search_options)

        # Print envelope details
        for envelope in results.envelopes:
            print(f"Envelope ID: {envelope.envelope_id}, Status: {envelope.status}")

    except ApiException as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}")
```

when i execute the method get_envelopes_by_email("exemple@gmail.com") i have the error `AttributeError: 'EnvelopesApi' object has no attribute 'select_header_accept'`
i have the version docusign-esign==3.7.1
thanks à lot[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJh7a.png)

I am expecting to get the list of enveloppe with the email address.

Comment: It seems that you're using the library according to the documentation, maybe showing the problem as an [issue on their repo](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-esign-python-client/issues) could give you a better answer. Also, for readability sake, put you imports at the top of you file, not in a function (see [PEP0008](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/#imports))

Comment: Please create an [API log](https://support.docusign.com/s/document-item?language=en_US&rsc_301&bundleId=jux1643235969954&topicId=poz1578456669909.html&_LANG=enus) of your API request to DocuSign. Then add the log to your question (edit your question).

Comment: version 3.7.1 is 3 years old, can you upgrade to version 3.23 and try again?

Comment: @InbarGazit Yes ! i tried to update it to the latest version and i have the same error :(

Answer (score 0):

@Achraf Ben Hamou I would suggest creating a support case with DocuSign support if you are still facing this issue. The support team will be able to take a more in depth look at your API logs